# figure's title is flashing on and off for frequently updated Matlab imshow()

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, imshow

I am updating my `figure` by calling `imshow()` once a second.
But for each update, the figure displays without the title, and then an instant later it displays with the title.
I checked Matlab Help but `imshow()` doesn't have a 'Name'  Name-Value pair argument.  So, there seems to be a delay between `imshow()` and `title()`.

```
if isempty( disparity_map_figure)   
    disparity_map_figure = figure('Name', 'DISPARITY LATEST');
else
    set(groot,'CurrentFigure',disparity_map_figure);
end
imshow(disparity_map, DisparityRange, 'colormap', jet ); 
title('DISTANCE DISPARITY - LATEST');
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because `imshow` takes long to load and display the data, thus while `imshow` is working you don't see the title, and once it finished showing the data then `title()` runs.

You can try to speed up the `imshow`by just changing the data every time. So the first time you run you code, run `h=imshow()`, but later just change `h.CData=disparity_map` in Matlab R2014b or `set(h,'Cdata',disparity_map)` for versions before R2014b.

Not sure if it will work, but I don't have the code to test so give it a go.

Comment: If this solution doesn't work, try adding a `draw now` command after setting the title.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar situation, and updating inner graphic components was not successful. A command like `set(h,'Title').String = "myTitle"` for example still produced flickering. However, the no-flickering magic came from a simple `hold on` instruction.

Here is an example that plays a video on a `gcf`, while displaying a new `text` at each frame - whithout the flashing effect. This works well with `gca` titles too.

```
v = VideoReader(videofilename);

while hasFrame(v)
  
  frame = readFrame(v);
  imshow(frame); 
  hold on;
  text(10,10, sprintf('Current time: %.6f sec', v.CurrentTime)) % text is displayed without flickering
  % title(sprintf('Current time: %.6f sec', v.CurrentTime))     % title works fine too

end
```

*Matlab R2021b on MacOS*

Comment: This has the effect of *adding* the image on top of the previous image, if you loop 100 times, you will have 100 images on top of each other in the figure window. You don't see them, but they're there, taking up memory and rendering time. The long you loop, the more sluggish it will all become. If Ander's suggestion doesn't work, try adding a `draw now` command after setting the title.

Comment: Good point - didn't check this. However, the textbook having a transparent background, the successive texts don't overlay on top of each other, each one presenting nicely shaped distinctive letters and numbers. So it's kind of a weird "toping".

Comment: `inshow` doesn’t do transparency.